# Summernote : Move buttons in the toolbar to the right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, summernote

The buttons in the toolbar of summernote are always left aligned. Is there a way I can change this alignment of toolbar buttons to right or center?

The default position is like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR8kO.png

I want to change the alignment of the buttons, so they will look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLylj.png

Comment: I've added an answer, but without the code it is hard to see what you are doing exactly.

Comment: I'm using Summernote editor for an application I'm working on.
It's working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can float the whole toolbar to the right with:

```
float:right;
```

You can do that with CSS.

e.g. the div containing the toolbar icons should be floated right. If there is no div containing the toolbar icons then put the icons within a div like below.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="toolbar-container">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.toolbar-container {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `float: right` to all the `btn-group` inside the toolbar :

```
.note-toolbar > .btn-group {
    float: right ;
}
```

Unfortunately it will reorder the `btn-group` so you have to update the configuration file to reverse the order.